# Master title for fencing

Tags: war, warfare, sword

When and where did the practice of calling either a fencing teacher or a great swordsman "master" originates from?  I am interested mainly in European primary sources, the older the better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was derived from the European guild system, most notably from German cities. Full members of a guild were called masters and allowed to teach others. Swordsmanship was simply another craft to be learned and taught.

For some additional sources, check out these online copies of historical [European martial arts & fencing books](http://www.thearma.org/masters.htm) and this [Wiki on historical European fighting arts](http://www.wiktenauer.com/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: LOL... I refused to post that answer due to "It can't POSSIBLY be that simple" :)   But you are correct. +1